# Подгрузить содержимое переменной в Image

Tags: python-3.x

```
animate = subprocess.check_output('ffmpeg -y -i file -loop 0 -c:v libwebp -lossless 0 -vf "[0:v] fps=5,select=\'between(t,'+str(time_v/4)+','+str(time_v/4+1)+')\',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,scale=-2:198" -f webp -', shell=True)
stream = BytesIO(animate)
img = Image.open(stream)
```

Сохраняю выходное изображение в переменную animate. Как содержимое переменной верно преобразовать, чтобы открыть  в

img = Image.open(stream)

Comment: Речь про time_v ? Вроде вы уже записали их в строку, в чем проблема на данный момен?

Comment: И вроде фунция ` subprocess.check_output` вернёт None и видимо вам нужно открыть файл созданный ffmpeg

Comment: Выходной файл не сохранял, точнее сохранил объект в переменную animate. То есть можно сохранить изображение, а затем открыть его в Image.open(stream), обрезать и снова сохранить. Рассчитываю найти решение при котором, предварительно не придется сохранять изображение, а сохранить объект в переменно, затем подгрузить в image, произвести манипуляции и только после это сохранять как изображение.

Comment: можно пример рабочего кода чтобы воспроизвести, пытаюсь запустить с `ffmpeg -y -i file -loop 0 -c:v libwebp -lossless 0 -vf "[0:v] fps=5,select=\'between(t,10,10)\',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,scale=-2:198" -f webp -` и ffmpeg выдает ошибку

Comment: Попробуйте `animate = subprocess.check_output('ffmpeg -y -i /var/www/2335.mp4 -loop 0 -c:v libwebp -lossless 0 -pix_fmt rgb24 -vf "[0:v] fps=5,select=\'between(t,0,3)\',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,scale=-2:198"  -r 10 -qscale 75  -f webp -', shell=True)`

Comment: функция  subprocess.check_output отдает вывод команды, то есть вывод ffmpeg это просто лог, а не файл как вам нужно

Comment: видимо нужно открывать `/var/www/2335.mp4` хотя не очень знаю ffmpeg и не могу сказать что вам в результате нужно

Comment: Возможно ли в переменную запомнить результат выходного файла. То есть не результат, а что на выходе как еслибы сохраняли изображение?

Comment: Это вопрос больше к `ffmpeg` может он вывести, но думаю результат его работы это файл и вам нужно его будет прочитать и уже передать в `Image`

Comment: Может вопрос поправить и описать что нужно от работы. ffmpeg ? Просто не очень понятен результат из-за этого

Comment: Необходимо анимированное изображение. Оно есть, сохраняет. Но, необходимо сохранить выходной результат в переменную и  в дальнейшем обработать изображение через Image. То есть предварительно  не сохраняя изображение как файл... Вопрос верно ли сохраняет или сохраняет логи, второй вопрос как конвектировать содержимое переменно чтобы подгрузить ee в img = Image.open(stream)